# Modelling ER diagrams with weak entities

Tags: database, database-design, data-modeling, entity-relationship

If an entity, say x, is dependent on multiple other entities but x does not have any key attributes (so x can not be a weak entity?). Then how should x be modelled in an ER diagram, assuming x has attributes and x has relationships with other entities (that it is not dependant on).

Comment: Can you please give an example ?

Answer (score 1):

By definition, entity sets which do not have sufficient attributes to form a primary key are known as **weak entity** sets and the entity sets which have a primary key are known as **strong entity** sets.

**Weak entities** are represented with double rectangular box in the ER Diagram and the identifying relationships are represented with double diamond. **Partial Key** attributes are represented with dotted lines.

A very common example, `Payment` and `Loan Payment`. `Payment` is the weak entity. `Loan Payment` is the identifying relationship and `Payment Number` is the partial key. `Primary Key` of the `Loan` along with the partial key would be used to identify the records.

[image]